# char* points to an int value, how to get the int value?

Tags: c, pointers

I read 4 bytes from a file like this:

```
char *size;
int rc = read(fd, &size, 4);
```

when I print size, it writes the correct value that size has to be:

```
printf("%d\n", size);
```

would print 200, which is exactly the thing that I had wrote in a file previously.

Now how can I get the value 200 as an int?

```
int s = *size;
```

doesn't work. What can I do?

Comment: What is the file format exactly? What do the four bytes you wrote represent?

Comment: I open the file like this:
    int fd= open("file", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_APPEND, S_IRWXU);

Comment: @Ehsan A file is a stream of bytes. If you want to write a multi-byte integer to a file, you need some way to encode that integer as a bunch of bytes. Somehow, you've encoded an integer as four bytes such that each byte represents part of that integer. What precisely is the rule you used for determining the value of each byte?

Comment: Sorry my comment was incomplete.

I open the file like this:
    int fd= open("file", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_APPEND, S_IRWXU);

and I want to write 200, like this:

int s = 200;

write(fd, &s, sizeof(s));

later I want to read, the value 200 back into an int value.

Comment: @Ehsan That won't work. DO NOT DO THAT. You have no idea what bytes you are writing to the file. (If you think you do, tell me what the first byte represents and where in the C standard you found that information.) It may happen to work by luck and that may trick you into thinking it's safe/reliable, but it's absolutely not.

Comment: Imagine if you're explaining how to read that data to someone else who is writing a similar program. They say, "Okay, the first byte is a 12, what does that mean?" Remember, a file is a stream of bytes. For the file to make sense, the writer and reader must agree on what each *byte* means. If you fail to do that, you have nothing.

Comment: it is printing 200! @M

Comment: @Ehsan It is because of a series of coincidences and not on any behavior that you can sanely rely on it. For example, `sizeof(char *)` and `sizeof(int)` happen to be the same on your platform, among other coincidences. (See my answer, you must properly decode each byte, and to do that you need to know what each byte encodes.)

Comment: @M.M Yeah that is what I am surprised about too

Comment: The code has really implicit casting from pointer to integer. But it's initially buggy as a hell. `int s = *size;` apparently reads some arbitrary memory.

Comment: the int value s has 4 bytes, correct? I want to write it in an empty file like  
write(fd, &s, sizeof(s));  and I just write that and nothing more. 

Later I want to read s back from file into an int, with read syscall. what is the correct way of doing this? @DavidSchwartz

Comment: @Ehsan Then what happens when your platform changes the size of an int to 8 bytes? Or when someone on a different platform tries to read your files? That is not a sane way to write C code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you've written here is unusual:

```
char *size;
int rc = read(fd, &size, 4);
```

The `read` command expects as its second argument the address of a location in which to put the bytes that are read back. Here, you're saying "please overwrite the bytes that make up my pointer with the value from the file." You do that and the write

```
printf("%d\n", size);
```

which means "please interpret the bytes of the pointer as though they were an integer, and print out whatever value that ends up being." This is an unusual way to do this because you're essentially taking a `char *`, which logically represents "where to look to find a character," and treating it as though it's a number. If you forget this and then try using `size` as though it really is a pointer, you'll almost certainly cause a segfault and the behavior is undefined.

In other words, your `char *` doesn't *point* to an integer value. The bytes that compose your `char *` literally *are* an integer value. This is why dereferencing it doesn't work; dereferencing means "follow the pointer and see what we find," but that pointer isn't meaningfully pointing anywhere.

Worse, since the size of a `char *` and the size of an integer don't have to be the same (on a 64-bit system, you'll likely find `sizeof(char *)` to be eight and `sizeof(int)` to be 4) it's possible that printing it out using `printtf` will read the wrong number of bytes.

If you want to read an integer, create an integer variable and then pass a pointer to it to `read`:

```
int size;
int result = read(fd, &size, sizeof(size));
```

This says "please read one bytes from the file descriptor for each byte in my `size` variable, and put those bytes into the location occupied by `size`." Here, you're being honest about what you're reading back - you say to read bytes into an integer, which is good because you're treating it as an integer, and you're more accurately saying to read `sizeof(size)` bytes rather than 4 bytes in case the size of an integer is different on your system.

If you're planning on reading raw bytes, you may want to even consider using a type like `uint32_t` or `int32_t` to more clearly indicate that you want specifically four bytes:

```
uint32_t size;
int result = read(fd, &size, sizeof(uint32_t));
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was very clear and helped a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the exact file format. Possibly:

```
int i = size[0] | 
    (size[1] << 8) |
    (size[2] << 16) |
    (size[3] << 24);
```

It could also be:

```
int i = size[3] | 
    (size[2] << 8) |
    (size[1] << 16) |
    (size[0] << 24);
```

You may need to dereference through a pointer to `unsigned char` instead of `char`. But we can't be sure without seeing the specification for the file format. What *precisely* do each of those four bytes represent?

Comment: I'm a bit surprised: printf("%d\n", size) works as intended as the OP claimed... hm

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava If so, it's by luck, and that's not a sensible way to write code!

Comment: This will fail miserably if `char` is signed.

Comment: @M.M It may or may not fail miserably if `char` is signed depending on what the bytes encode which we still don't know. See my last paragraph. (I fixed the out of bounds access, thanks.)

Comment: Usually you choose endianess and work with it. Simplest way is to use `htonl()` et al.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to be portable, here's another approach to save your integer in a file...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// store an integer value into comma-separated,
// human-readable text file and retrieve the value
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int value = 400;
    int read_value = 0;

    if ((fp = fopen("test-int-store", "w+")) == NULL) {
        perror("fopen:");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!fprintf(fp, "%d,\n", value)) {
        perror("fopen:");
        exit(1);
    }

    rewind(fp);

    if (!fscanf(fp, "%d,\n", &read_value)) {
        perror("fopen:");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("read_value=%d\n", read_value);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know that I could just do:

```
int size;
int rc = read(fd, &size, 4);
```

and then I have back the written size in the file as int.

Comment: If this works, it's only by luck. Again, this is not a sane way to write C code.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz , I accept, I am very new to C language. What's the correct way of doing this using only open/read/write/close syscalls?
1) define `int size = 200`
2) write the value of `size` into an empty file
3) later read back what you had written in that file.
4) retrieve the value of size from what you read.

Comment: Look at my answer, or learn how to use functions like `ntohl`. Or store the number in text.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the level of C portability fanaticism:

1. High level

   ```
   union {
     unsigned char c[sizeof(int)];
     int i;
   }c_i;
   ```

and then

```
char *p;

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++)
   c_i.c[i] = (unsigned char *)(p + i);
```

c_i.i contains the integer.

2. Low level. As on the machines used nowadays strict aliasing rules are IMO a bit too strict - pointer punning works in 100% (maybe except situations when char is not aligned and uC does not allow unaligned access)

   ```
   char *p = .....

   int *i = p;
   ```

before lynch please give any example (except the one I gave) when pointer punning invokes an UB. Except silly nonsense ones please:

```
void foo(int *i, long long *l) {   *i = 10;   *l = 20;   printf("%d\n",i); }

char k[100];

foo (k,k);
```